# I am not able to show the css files on flask app getting error?

Tags: python, html, flask

Hello can someone help me resolve this issue. I tried the possible solutions of stackoverflow, but still I am getting error. I am a beginner in Flask. Removed some middle part of the code as I wasn't able to post it.
I am getting 404 error on few files:

[image]

My HTML template code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <title>Indus HTML5 Free Responsive Template | Template stock</title>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/css/et-lineicon.css') }}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='/css/style.css') }}" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,400italic,500italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!--[if IE]>
            <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Preloader -->
        <div class="animationload">
            <div class="loader">
                Loading...
            </div>
        </div> 
        <!-- End Preloader -->
                           
        <!-- =========================
                 FOOTER
        ========================== -->

        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="container text-center">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <ul class="social list-inline">
                            <li class="social-btn" id="fb"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                            <li class="social-btn" id="tw"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                            <li class="social-btn" id="tbl"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tumblr"></i></a></li>
                            <li class="social-btn" id="pin"><a href="#"><i class="fa  fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
                            <li class="social-btn" id="flk"><a href="#"><i class="fa  fa-flickr"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <p class="copyright">Copyright© 2016 <a href="http://templatestock.co">Template Stock</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
            
        <!-- JAVASCRIPTS -->
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/js/jquery.lwtCountdown-1.0.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/js/jquery.stellar.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/js/animated.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='/js/main.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My Directories:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache of your browser?

Comment: You are getting 404 on all your static files (except the ones that have a double slash ```//``` in the path). Are you sure your static file path is correct especially in relation to your template folder?

Comment: Hey thanks! But I have shared the code and you can see I have used a single slash everywhere. That's why I am really confused.

Comment: 1) You have not used a single slash everywhere. If you look closely at the lines with a 308 status, they have a double slash ```//``` somewhere. 2) It is not the issue of a single slash. You have relative paths (i.e. your links start with a slash ```/```) which means you are telling the system to look for those paths starting from the directory of the current page. You have to ask yourself - are those paths correct? Do you instead have to move 1, 2 or more directories up (i.e. ```./```, ```../```, ```../../```). If you post your folder structure, we might be able to offer more help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to place the static folder in the main directory and not inside the template  folder.

```
.\home
   .\templates
    - index.html
   .\static
    - css
    - img
    - fonts
    - js
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I was making the mistake for the whole time.